# Combining checks at the beginning of a method

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have several methods that are similar to the following:

```
@property
def tpr_num_days(self):
    """
    The duration, in days, of the TPR interval.
    """
    if not self.prices:
        raise RuntimeError("Must initialize self.prices first.")

    # do something

@property
def revenue_during_tpr_is_greatest(self):
    """
    Tells us if the Revenue that was generated during the TPR was both greater
    than the revenue that was generated in the same-duration interval before the TPR and after the TPR.
    """
    if not self.prices:
        raise RuntimeError("Must initialize self.prices first.")

    # do something

def build_pricing_data(self):
    """
    This will build a list of pricing objects.

    Note that we are currently excluding "returns" because the price of the returned
    item may be different than the current price of the product, which could open up
    a can of worms trying to track down when that item was purchased.
    """
    cursor.execute('''SELECT
                            date,
                            max(if(offer_code='sdbuy', price, null)) sd_buy_price,
                            max(if(offer_code='hdbuy', price, null)) hd_buy_price,
                            max(if(offer_code='sdrent', price, null)) sd_rent_price,
                            max(if(offer_code='hdrent', price, null)) hd_rent_price,
                            sum(revenue) revenue
                      FROM price_date WHERE apple_id=%s and territory=%s and revenue > 0
                      GROUP BY date
                      ORDER BY date
                      ''', (self.apple_id, self.territory))

    # let's make sure it's re-initialized in case it's called multiple times.
    self.prices = []     
    for row in cursor:
        pricing_obj = {"date": item[0], "SDBUY": item[1], "HDBUY": item[2], "SDRENT": item[3], "HDRENT": item[4], "REVENUE": item[5]}
        self.prices.append(pricing_obj)
```

Instead of having this `if` statement at the start of dozens of methods, what would be a better way to encapsulate that?

Comment: Instead of checking that the object isn't in an invalid state it'd be better to prevent it from ever getting into one. Can you initialize `self.prices` in the constructor? If not, why not?

Comment: @JohnKugelman not really. It's a generalized class. And sometimes someone will use it with external data that they load in, and the way they "load it in" is with some of the helper methods within this class itself.

Comment: Can every method in the class be wrapped? Or is it only a select subset of methods?

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse not all. Just a few.

Comment: What if you turn `price` into a property of the class and within that property you raise the exception if that property was never set.

Comment: If you want a decorator solution I can write one of those. Metaclass is also possible but there needs to be someway to tell which methods require `price` to exist. Are you only checking if `price` exists in methods that use it?

Comment: Can you show an example of someone loading data in? I still feel like you should prevent the situation. You could have a variety of static `load` methods that return constructed objects. Or you could use a builder pattern to allow for complex initialization before creating the actual object that gets used.

Comment: @JohnKugelman I added an example of building the pricing data from within the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a function decorator:

```
import functools

def requires_price(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(obj, *args, **kwargs):
        if not obj.prices:
            raise RuntimeError("Must initialize self.prices first.")

        return func(obj, *args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper
```

Which would be used like this:

```
@property
@requires_price
def tpr_num_days(self):
    ... # do something
```

Or you could go a step further and implement the decorator as a [descriptor](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html), which would let you omit the `@property`:

```
class price_property:
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        if instance is None:
            return self

        if not instance.prices:
            raise RuntimeError("Must initialize self.prices first.")

        return self.func(instance)
```

Which is used like this:

```
@price_property
def tpr_num_days(self):
    ... # do something
```

Comment: Wrap the decorator in one more layer and you can pass the attribute you want to require instead of always checking for `price`. Or check for multiple attributes.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a method to do the check.

```
def validate_prices(self):
    if not self.prices:
        raise RuntimeError("Must initialize self.prices first.")
```

and then put `self.validate_prices()` at the beginning of each function.

It only saves one line, but you don't have to repeat the same error message every time.

If you want something more automatic, you'd probably have to define a metaclass that adds this code to every property method.

Comment: thanks. Can you explain how `you'd probably have to define a metaclass` would work? Also, what about having a decorator, would that be another option?

Comment: Sorry, python metaclasses and decorators are a little out of my expertise. The decorator might be a simpler solution, though.